# Site is "Temporarily Unavailable"

Tags: installation

I get "Service Unavailable" when I go to my (hosted, not local) test site.

It had been working just fine until I decided to swap databases today.

I deleted the old database and replaced it with the new database.  I kept the database name the same.  I changed the username and password in cPanel and then duplicated those changes in my craft/db.php file... But no dice...  I get the nice little warning:

> **Service Unavailable**
>
> Our site is temporarily unavailable.  Please try again later.

I have checked more than once, the path, db name, username and password all check out.  Any suggestions?  ...other than start over

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Others have said what the problem is, but in the interest of clarity for future readers...

**Cause**: The database is expecting a newer version of Craft's filesystem than you have.

**Solution**: Replace the /app folder with one from a fresh Craft download and visit your admin trigger URL

Answer (score 2):

Based on [your comments](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/21489/help-my-site-is-temporarily-unavailable-huh/21491?noredirect=1#comment29711_21491) to @benface, I believe your database is using a version of Craft ahead of your files.

Answer (score 1):

Try going to /admin, you should get a clearer error message.

Comment: No joy.  I just get the following    Oops! Craft CMS does not support backtracking to this version. Please upload Craft CMS 2.6.2988 or later.   ...I should note that I had changed my admin page to a different name, this is the error I get when I go to the renamed admin page.

Comment: I believe that means your database is using a version of Craft ahead of your files.

Comment: Yep, that is what I forgot to check.

Comment: @Stephen Callender had it correct... I forgot to check if the Craft versions matched. They did not.